# How to Modify the HTTP Response Using Filters in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, http, filter

Modifying the HTTP Response Using Filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question relates to ASP.NET, not Java. This might help:

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2008/04/13/What-is-the-Difference-between-an-httpModule-and-an-httpHandler_3F00_.aspx

Answer (score 1):

These kind of components are called filters in the Java world. They are capable of modifying requests/responses before they are dispachted to the handler component resp. before the response is delivered to the client.

In ASP.NET these kind of components are called [HTTP Modules](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020417.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> ### response
>
> **Purpose**
>
> The response object is an instance of the Servlet API's
>   `HttpServletResponse` class
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> class BookController {
>   def downloadFile = {
>       byte[] bytes = // read bytes
>       response.outputStream << bytes
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The Servlet API's `HttpServletResponse` class can be used within
>   Grails to perform all typical activities such as writing out binary
>   data, writing directly to the response and sending error response
>   codes to name but a few.

Quoted from [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Servlet%20API/response.html).

Comment: Please use proper attribution when you copy/paste from an external website.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, response filters have been the way to do this in ASP.NET.  However, they suffer from some serious cache-related issues, both in IIS6 (tougher to notice) and IIS7.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348756/) includes a KB article with more detail.